# Meaning of "continuing explosion of case law"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can somebody please explain to me the meaning of "continuing explosion of case law" in the following paragraph take from [EU Intellectual Property Law and Policy](https://books.google.com/books?id=d4AwDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=A+continuing+explosion+of+case+law+affecting+intellectual+property+is+decided+by+a+number+of+EU+institutions&source=bl&ots=CI8RL0g715&sig=di_ulqLuEM2k3zJpo4n7EQPiVfw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE0_DFtavRAhUFLmMKHQORAqkQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=A%20continuing%20explosion%20of%20case%20law%20affecting%20intellectual%20property%20is%20decided%20by%20a%20number%20of%20EU%20institutions&f=false) by Catherine Seville?

> Digital Single Market and the Innovation Union are currently high-priority strategic objectives for the Commission. Community activity in this field is extensive, and the proposals are increasingly detailed and well publicized. There are significant developments in both high-level policy matters, and practical measures. A **continuing explosion of case law** affecting intellectual property is decided by a number of EU institutions, within its judicial framework. Their practical impact is considerable.

I have to translate it and I'm having a hard time since I can't fully understand it.

Comment: Thank you! Here is the entire paragraph: "Digital Single Market and the Innovation Union are currently high-priority strategic
objectives for the Commission. Community activity in this field is extensive, and the
proposals are increasingly detailed and well publicised. There are significant developments in both high-level policy matters, and practical measures. A continuing explosion
of case law affecting intellectual property is decided by a number of EU institutions,
within its judicial framework. Their practical impact is considerable."

Comment: The paragraph is from a book entitled 'EU Intellectual Property Law and Policy' by Catherine Seville

Comment: You should look up "case law" in your native language English dictionary and it will help you a great deal with the answer below.

Comment: The sentence can be rephrased to: The number of cases on intellectual property, which can't be decided based on previous judicial precedents,  is increasing so rapidly that they are decided by a number of EU institutions.

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me. I played with the sentence a bit and the result was somewhat a bit more natural.

Comment: Glad I helped. Please visit Help Center and read the guidelines. It is important to include all the surrounding sentences and context as @Hank advised. Good luck and welcome.

Answer (score 3):

> #### Case Law
>
> - Reported decisions of appeals courts and other courts which make new interpretations of the law and, therefore, can be cited as precedents.

([Law Dictionary](http://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=148))

***Continuing explosion of case law*** is referencing a high-flowing, continuous amount of precedents being set. **Explosion** is used here to show that the amount of increase is very rapid. In this case, those precedents are being set in relation to intellectual property.

The end of the paragraph is emphasizing the fact that this continuous flow of case law affecting intellectual property is having a considerable impact on the community proposals mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: I was writing up an answer. Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

One very common meaning of [explosion](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/explosion) is "a rapid increase, esp. in a population". So in recent years there has been a very rapid increase in IP case law: far more lawsuits are coming before the courts, and far more court cases result in additional case law. (To anybody in the field, this is a truism; whether it is good or bad is arguable.)